# android tcp client file receive

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to send a file (png to be specific) over sockets from python server to android client. I know that my python server is sending the data, I just can't figure out how to receive the data on the android side. Here is what the code looks like to receive the file.

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/tmp/test.png";     
        try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.1.129", 29877);

             is = socket.getInputStream();
             out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
            for(int c = is.read(temp,0,1024); c > 0; c = is.read(temp,0,1024)){
                out.write(temp,0,c);
                Log.d("debug tag", out.toString());
            }
            Log.d("debug tag", temp.toString());

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from socket in 1K chunks and saving them into a file. Then you try to interpret *the last chunk* as a bitmap. This doesn't work.

Either read your image from the file after you saved it, or buffer it all in memory.

Comment: how would I buffer it all in memory? example?

Comment: You can use something like `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html

Comment: wow dude, thanks I can't believe I didn't realize I was trying to read only the last chunk...stupid...Thanks a lot.